# CSS buttons (text or image)

Tags: html, css, browser, user-interface, web

I would like to know if I should create CSS buttons or image buttons for my site. What is better? The problem is that the text is formatted with Helvetica Neue (I like that font very much) and I can't use it as a web font because of copyright issues.

If I create the buttons in CSS they look beautiful in the browser but get resized when the user has chosen a different text-size for their browsers.

Image buttons have the advantage I can embed my font but do not look that good as CSS buttons. Also in that case I had to make Retina-versions for the buttons (just for the future when any PC has a Retina-display).

Is there a web-safe alternative to Helvetica Neue? Should I disable the resizing of my button div-containers? What's today's standard when it comes to website buttons?

Comment: Use [WebMasters SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) for the question.

Comment: _If I create the buttons in CSS they look beautiful in the browser but get resized when the user has chosen a different text-size for their browsers._ Why is this a problem?

Comment: Because resized buttons do not look very good (large txt = large button).

Comment: Have you seen this thread? Seems to suggest Liberation Sans as an alternative. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8827/helvetica-neue-equivalent-on-google-web-fonts

Comment: @drpelz Yeah, you really want to let the users control their own browser. I'ts good UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helvetica Neue can in fact be licensed as a web font:

http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/neue-helvetica?QueryFontType=Web#product_top

I would personally stay very far away from image buttons (for the reasons you yourself outlined), and would rather fall back to a similar font (e.g. [Arimo](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Arimo) on Google Web Fonts) than have to worry about generating (and re-generating) a bunch of images.

Comment: Thanks for your help!:) Yeah I don't like to save dozens of image buttons, either. Pure CSS buttons with text save a lot of work. But I was not sure about this topic because it's the first time that I'm involved in a big website project!

Answer (score -1):

There are some amazing CSS buttons that have effects though some images might suit the theme of your site better. If you want some CSS buttons go to [Styling buttons with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384304/styling-buttons-with-css/51112564#51112564).

Hope this helps.